# Polymer dom-repeat not reflecting changes in array

Tags: javascript, highcharts, polymer

I am trying to use a dom repeat template with a custom element wrapping highcharts (https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart). It is mostly working except when the data gets changed the charts do not reflect it.

The dom-repeat template:

```
  <template id="scenarioCharts" is="dom-repeat" items="{{chartOptions}}" as="chartOption">
    <highcharts-chart highchart-options="{{chartOption}}" />
  </template>
```

The Polymer code to build `chartOptions` (which is a property with notify true):

```
observers: [
  'buildChartOptions(scenarios)',
],
buildChartOptions(scenarios) {
  var i = 0;
  this.set('chartOptions', []);
  for (i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i += 1) {
    this.push('chartOptions', buildCustomChartOptions(scenarios[i]));
  }
},
```

If I remove the line `this.set('chartOptions', []);` the dom-repeat keeps the old ones and adds the new charts.  I have also tried a lot of different things with `splices` and `notifySplices` but have had no luck producing the desired result which is the old charts being replaced by the new ones.

Thanks

Comment: This is possibly related to this [`<dom-repeat>` bug](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1713#issuecomment-108729265).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would refer to the same bug mentioned by tony19.

Your code seems to be a good workaround, though I'd probably create a local array, populate it and set it again, like this:

```
buildChartOptions(scenarios) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i += 1) {
    newArray.push(buildCustomChartOptions(scenarios[i]));
  }
  this.set('chartOptions', newArray);
}
```

Another alternative would be to push your changes to the array and then force the dom-repeat to render, by doing a `this.$.scenarioCharts.render();`. You'd need to try it though, I'm not sure it would work:

```
buildChartOptions(scenarios) {
    for (var i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i += 1) {
        this.push('chartOptions',buildCustomChartOptions(scenarios[i]));
    }
    this.$.scenarioCharts.render();
}
```

Additionally, even though it does not concern your question, I would recomend declaring a function in polymer like this:

`buildChartOptions: function(scenarios) { }`

instead of

`buildChartOptions(scenarions) { }`

I sometimes forget and do the same you did, and the result is compatibility issues with Internet Explorer or Firefox... However if you do as suggested, everything will work fine.

Comment: forcing the render worked when i put it after the `this.set('chartOptions',[])`.

Comment: So you still need to set the chartOptions array to []... that's a pitty, I was hoping that the render would destroy the dom-repeat contents and re-render it with the new array content, but it seems you really need to change the array first.